# Talend Data preparation : Mongodb already installed locally on this computer

Tags: mongodb, talend

I am trying to install Talend Data Preparation V1.3 on my windows server 2012R2.

I have uninstalled previous version 1.2 and deleted all directories related to it from my machine.
Now when i am trying to install v1.3 it is giving me the following error.
"MongoDB is ALREADY installed locally on this computer. Please either uninstall it or use "External Mongo DB" option to proceed."

Currently I dont have any external mongodb or can install it.

Please help me how to get rid of this.

Comment: can you check it in services?? `services.msc`

Comment: How did u installed? Team viewer are you available?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to remove mongoDB from services list by running the following command:

```
sc delete talend-mongodb-6.4.1
```

I restarted and errors stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Open `regedit.msc` and delete mongodb registry file from

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\
```

Answer (score 0):

please delete your previous mongodb registry from local dir

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command as administrator  will uninstall existing MongoDB.

```
C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /x {16F5A406-2CA8-4A93-84EC-B67B7B5D55CE} /qb
```

Note : {16F5A406-2CA8-4A93-84EC-B67B7B5D55CE} is the Product Code {GUID} of the MSI. Can be Found in 
RegEdit > HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{guid}

Comment: the above is for Talend 6.4.1 for any new other version please verify GUID first.